# Passing arguments to anonymous Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, dom-events, anonymous-methods

Consider the code below:

```
this.usedIds = 0;

this.SendData = function(data)
{
    var id = this.usedIds;
    this.usedIds++;

    this.xmlHttpThing.open("POST", "/Upload.aspx", true);
    this.xmlHttpThing.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var currentObject = this;
    this.xmlHttpThing.onreadystatechange = function() { currentObject.UploadComplete(id) };
    this.xmlHttpThing.send(data);
};
this.UploadComplete = function(id)
{
    if (this.xmlHttpThing.readyState == 4)
    {
        //First time id is 0
        //Second time id is 0                 <<<--------- Why??
        //Third time id is 1
        //Fourth time id is 2
        //Fifth time id is 3 ....         

        this.SendData("blabla");
    }
};
```

Why does the id I pass to the anonymous function get delayed by one call after the first call?

Only seems to be this way in Firefox, in IE the `UploadComplete` receive the ids in the correct order.

In the second loop I can stop the debugger at the send(data)-line and confirm that the id is actually 1 but when I get to the `UploadComplete` it turns out to be 0 in that argument :(

**EDIT: Found solution:**
Disable Console-logging in FireBug.

Comment: Probably the "consider the code below" triggered it. Code should *follow* an explanation in plain English, not preceed it. Most users here have an aversion against "fix my code" style questions, and this one looks like one at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the Console-logging in Firebug solved the problem!

Comment: figures its something simple like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too in the past.  I don't remember exactly what caused it, but I fixed it by moving the increment to the response handler.

```
this.UploadComplete = function(id)
{
    if (this.xmlHttpThing.readyState == 4)
    {      
        this.usedIDs++;
        this.SendData("blabla");
    }
};
```

Edit:  after thinking about it, my case may have been different from yours.  Why not increment `this.usedIDs` when you assign `id`?

```
var id = this.usedIDs++;
```